# Is there a npm registry for development?

Tags: npm

Is there a NPM registry that I can use for testing and development?
Or do I need to setup one myself and mirror the official registry (somehow!?)

Thanks.

Comment: By 'testing and development', do you mean developing an application that uses npmjs.org? Or do you mean a place to test and develop packages to place on the registry?

Comment: I mean "a place to test and develop packages to place on A "clone" registry". I am developing a CI system and don't want to publish/unpublish to the official registry.

Comment: If you just need npm to pull packages from somewhere and don't want to host them publicly, I tend to favor private git repos as dependencies. The docs cover it briefly [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies). I use tags so you can consistently pull the same source.

Comment: `verdaccio`.  I've got it setup on a Linux Container.  Works well.

Answer (score 0):

After some detailed searching I found the following answer:

http://thejackalofjavascript.com/maintaining-a-private-npm-registry/